# Android camera preview freezes suddenly

Tags: java, android, camera

I have implemented an android camera with the help of official developer.android.com tutorial. The app is working fine sometimes but about 3/5 of times the preview of the camera freezes after some rotation and clicking the buttons or even without these works (other elements don't freeze). The cutest part is that when I debug the application the preview doesn't stuck but when I want to run the app normally sometimes the problem happens.

Here is my fullScreen Class which is consist of the codes that android studio generated for fullScreen activity and the codes for implementing surfaceHolder.Callback and camera stuff.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

...   // some constants here
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        SurfaceView cameraSufaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        // Accessing front camera to take picture
        mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();

        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = cameraSufaceView.getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);

        } else {
            // Alter user
        }

    /**
     * Gets an instance of front facing camera if available
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
        int cameraCount;
        Camera cam = null;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                try {
                    cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        return cam;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
//            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(needs degree here);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        releaseCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mCamera == null)
            mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
```

When this problem happens some errors appear in the LogCat but they are not really informative. here are they:

```
26893-26893/com.naviiid.retinaflash E/art﹕ No implementation found for void java.lang.Runtime.appStartupEnd() (tried Java_java_lang_Runtime_appStartupEnd and Java_java_lang_Runtime_appStartupEnd__)
09-16 01:34:09.336  26893-26893/com.naviiid.retinaflash E/ActivityThread﹕ appStartupEnd :
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.appStartupEnd(ActivityThread.java:305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void java.lang.Runtime.appStartupEnd() (tried Java_java_lang_Runtime_appStartupEnd and Java_java_lang_Runtime_appStartupEnd__)
            at java.lang.Runtime.appStartupEnd(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.appStartupEnd(ActivityThread.java:305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

The only clue that I have found so far is that sometimes android calls onPause method even if the activity isn't paused. For getting instance of the camera again I call `openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread()` in onResume method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JordiCastilla I respect your opinion but it would be great if you provide more information about the problems in question?

Comment: I wont read all your messy code, read article and learn how to ask... if you don't SO is not the place for this question.

Comment: @JordiCastilla I made the code simpler. Is it better now?

Comment: NO, it's not, I asked you to read the article.... you did??? **Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: @JordiCastilla Yes I did. I think this code is enough to reproduce the problem. I haven't deleted comments which I think would help the reader to understand the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89796/discussion-between-jordi-castilla-and-navid-eivazzadeh).